# NoReverseMatch on twitter auth with django-socialregistration

Tags: django, twitter, twitter-oauth

I followed the instructions at https://github.com/flashingpumpkin/django-socialregistration to get twitter auth for my little **django app**.

The only thing I am unsure of is where the urls have to go, so I added to my url patterns.

```
('^$', include('socialregistration.urls')),
```

Now, I get:

```
TemplateSyntaxError at /

Caught NoReverseMatch while rendering: Reverse for 'twitter_redirect' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found.
```

This is strange as socialregistration.urls does not need any arguments as per https://github.com/flashingpumpkin/django-socialregistration/blob/master/socialregistration/urls.py

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the `twitter_redirect` url is only included if you have defined a `TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY` in settings.py - have you?